# Photoshop script hide and save with level name

Tags: photoshop

I have a Photoshop file with around 200 levels, I need to save for web every single level with the level's name hiding the other levels...Is there any way to do that with script?
Thanks

Comment: Levels?? Do you mean layers? and do you mean save out the layers name as the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will save out each layer as a jpeg, named after the layer name. You don't need to hide the layers as you go; instead each layer it gets duplicated as a new image, flattened, saved and then closed. Won't work with any groups (normally you have to pay extra for that ;) )

```
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
var numOfLayers = srcDoc.layers.length;
var jpegQuality = 12;

for (var i = numOfLayers -1; i >= 0  ; i--)
{
  var theLayerName = srcDoc.layers[i].name;
  var theFile = srcDoc.path;
  srcDoc.activeLayer = srcDoc.artLayers[i];
  var id2784 = charIDToTypeID( "Mk  " );
  var desc707 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id2785 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
  var ref508 = new ActionReference();
  var id2786 = charIDToTypeID( "Dcmn" );
  ref508.putClass( id2786 );
  desc707.putReference( id2785, ref508 );
  var id2787 = charIDToTypeID( "Nm  " );
  desc707.putString( id2787, theLayerName );
  var id2788 = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );
  var ref509 = new ActionReference();
  var id2789 = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
  var id2790 = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
  var id2791 = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
  ref509.putEnumerated( id2789, id2790, id2791 );
  desc707.putReference( id2788, ref509 );
  executeAction( id2784, desc707, DialogModes.NO );
  app.activeDocument.flatten();
  SaveForWeb(theFile, jpegQuality);
  app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
  app.activeDocument = srcDoc;
}

function SaveForWeb(saveFile, jquality)
{
  var sfwOptions = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb(); 
  sfwOptions.format = SaveDocumentType.JPEG; 
  sfwOptions.includeProfile = false; 
  sfwOptions.interlaced = 0; 
  sfwOptions.optimized = true; 
  sfwOptions.quality = jquality; 
  activeDocument.exportDocument(saveFile, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, sfwOptions);
}
```